# Understanding boot loader code to set the A20 gate

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader, gdt

Okay guys , I just tried to understand the code that helps in accessing the memory above 1Mb . I am writing the required snippet below . I will write what I understood , I just need the confirmation that what I understood is right or not ( I am self-studying OS ) . Thanks in advance

```
seta20.1:
  inb $0x64,%al # Wait for not busy
  testb $0x2,%al
  jnz seta20.1

  movb $0xd1,%al # 0xd1 -> port 0x64
  outb %al,$0x64

seta20.2:
  inb $0x64,%al # Wait for not busy
  testb $0x2,%al
  jnz seta20.2

  movb $0xdf,%al # 0xdf -> port 0x60
  outb %al,$0x60
```

In `seta20.1` first we are getting status from keyboard-controller ( mkbc ) to check whether it os okay to write something to it . Once it is free we write `0xd1` to it which goes in it's buffer which will ultimately set the output port to write .

In `seta20.1` we are checking first whether the mkbc has read it and set the output port or not . Once done we send the data `0xdf` which will set the A20 gate which will ultimately allow us to access the memory above 1Mb .

Is my understanding right ? If not please correct me at the right places .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are so many keyboard controller wait calls needed when enabling the A20 gate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21825241/are-so-many-keyboard-controller-wait-calls-needed-when-enabling-the-a20-gate)

Comment: @HansPassant Is my understanding right ?